# Kubernetes - config map templated variables

Tags: kubernetes

I have two env vars in a pod (or a config map):
- `TARGET_URL=http://www.example.com`
- `TARGET_PARAM=param`

Is there any way for me to provide a third env var which is derived from both these vars, something like `${TARGET_URL}/mysite/${TARGET_PARAM}`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible right now, without a 3rd party tool. regarding [api ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#envvarsource-v1-core) it does not support multi variable in YAML. But I will tell you about a 3rd party tool -- Helm

It is possible to achieve it using Helm. your template will look like:

```
 containers:
    - name: {{.Values.Backend.name }}
      image: "{{ .Values.Backend.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.Backend.image.tag }}"
      imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.Backend.image.pullPolicy }}"
      args:
        - name: TARGET_URL
          value: {{ .Value.URL}}
        - name: TARGET_PARAM
          value: {{ .Value.PARAM}}
        - name: URL
          value: {{ .Value.URL }}/mysite/{{ .Value.PARAM}}
```

and you will add to the file `values.yaml` parameters for  `TARGET_URL` and `TARGET_PARAM`

```
URL: http://www.example.com
PARAM: param
```

Answer (score 2):

For environment variables (and a couple of other fields in the pod spec, including `args` and `command`) there is a Make-like `$(VARIABLE)` name that will get expanded; see for example [the documentation for `.env.value`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#envvar-v1-core).  This could look like:

```
env:
  - name: TARGET_URL
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        key: cm
        name: TARGET_URL
  - name: TARGET_PARAM
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        key: cm
        name: TARGET_PARAM
  - name: TARGET_DETAIL_URL
    value: $(TARGET_URL)/mysite/$(TARGET_PARAM)
```

If you are depending on mounting a ConfigMap into a container as files, then it can only contain static content; this trick won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using an init script that you can call at docker entry point.